# Aggregate over groups of columns

Tags: python, pandas

Based on the data frame

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(2, 6)), columns=list('ABCDEF'))
print(df)
   A   B   C   D   E   F
0  82  63  71  74  71  27
1  90   9  74  35  38  43
```

how can I calculate the mean for each disjoint group of three columns, such that the resulting data frame looks like

```
   meanABC meanDEF
0  72      57.33
1  57.66   38.66
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is create `MultiIndex` first, then get new columns names for `rename` and last is possible use `mean` by second level of `MultiIndex`:

```
np.random.seed(2019)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(2, 6)), columns=list('ABCDEF'))
print(df)
    A   B   C   D   E   F
0  72  31  37  88  62  24
1  29  15  12  16  48  71

df.columns = [df.columns, np.arange(len(df.columns)) // 3]

c = 'mean' + df.columns.to_frame().groupby(1)[0].apply(''.join)
print (c)
1
0    meanABC
1    meanDEF
Name: 0, dtype: object

df = df.mean(axis=1, level=1).rename(columns=c)
print (df)
     meanABC  meanDEF
0  46.666667     58.0
1  18.666667     45.0
```

Answer (score 2):

try the below hope this helps:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(2, 6)), columns=list('ABCDEF'))
print(df)
```

Ouput will be :

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
0   2  89  68  48  13  17
1  43   9  98   9  18  94
```

Now follow the steps:

```
columns = list(df.columns)
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(0,len(columns),3):
    new_df['mean'+"".join(columns[i:i+3])] = df[columns[i:i+3]].mean(axis=1)
```

Ouput will be :

```
    meanABC     meanDEF
0   53.0    26.000000
1   50.0    40.333333
```